# Как сделать ограничение по вычисляемому свойству?

Tags: lsfusion

Решаю задачу [Турнирная таблица](https://docs.lsfusion.org/ru/Score_table/).
Сделал вычисляемые свойства "Количество голов забитых командой" (сумма голов забитых игроками команды в текущей игре):

```
hostGoals 'Х голы' (Game game) = GROUP SUM scorergoalsScored(Scorers scorers) IF typeTeam(scorers) = TypeTeam.host; 
guestGoals 'Г голы' (Game game) = GROUP SUM scorergoalsScored(Scorers scorers) IF typeTeam(scorers) = TypeTeam.guest;
```

Далее создаю ограничение:

```
CONSTRAINT hostGoals(Game game) = guestGoals(game) MESSAGE 'Игра не может закончиться вничью';
```

Но получаю ошибку:

> 04 окт 2020 09:26:27,124 ERROR StartLogger - Exception while starting
> logics instance:  Вычисление классов свойства : p948 '(SET) p922 ''
> [HockeyStats(57:12)]'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут дело в том, что вы при объявлении hostGoals нигде game не использовали. То есть нужно еще одно условие в конец добавить.

```
hostGoals 'Х голы' (Game game) = GROUP SUM scorergoalsScored(Scorers scorers) IF typeTeam(scorers) = TypeTeam.host AND game(scorers) = game;
```

Хотя да ошибка не очень информативна. Возможно для частных случаев (когда например параметр просто не используется) имеет смысл добавить дополнительные проверки.